# My armature disappeared in pose/object mode

Tags: rigging, armature, layers

[image]My armature is not visible in object/pose mode. I may have moved it into a layer but I'm not sure how to make it reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you've done, but your "Attacker Rigg" only has one bone, the one that is visible in your screen shot.  Your "Attacker rigg.001" has a full skeleton, but you have it hidden in Pose mode.  To see it

- Go to object mode
- Deselect all (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Select `Attacker rigg.001` in the outliner.
- Go to pose mode (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Select all (shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Unhide all (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>H</kbd>)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "In Front" turned on for your armature?
Have you tried showing all hidden objects with Alt+H?
Lastly, do you have Extras turned on in your Viewport Overlays?

There's a wide variety of problems you *could* be having, those are just three that come to mind

Comment: Hi Josephhansen, thank you for your response. I've tried your possible solutions but still no luck. The only way I see the armature is in edit mode.

Comment: In that case, upload your Blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and add a link to it in your question so that we can have a look.

Comment: Hi John Eason, here's my link https://pasteall.org/blend/6a346a23fe2540c9975b4870c271ac9c Thanks